# How to replace all id pings with tag?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I need to parse a discord message to a MySQL db and i got it all figured out, except for the pings . . . I'd like them to be automatically converted in to the tag of the user pinged.

I have no idea on how to do it

the message shows as the regular `message.content` and eider it or a copy of it needs to be corrected with what previously described also if there are multiple in the message, form different people.

Example of the result I'd like to get, from `stuff, message, stuff <@idofuser> more stuff, more stuf, end` to `stuff, message, stuff @username#discriminator more stuff, morestuff, end`

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end i found a solution, in this example the message is what discord passes you with the on message function:

```
var mentions = [];
message.mentions.users.forEach(user => {
    mentions.push({"userId": user.id, "username": user.username, "discriminator": user.discriminator});
});
var messageContent = message.content;
for (mention of mentions) {
    if(messageContent.includes(mention.userId)) {
        messageContent = messageContent.replace(new RegExp("<@"+mention.userId+">", 'g'), "@"+mention.username+"#"+mention.discriminator);
        messageContent = messageContent.replace(new RegExp("<@!"+mention.userId+">", 'g'), "@"+mention.username+"#"+mention.discriminator);
        }

    }
```

sorry to bother you, hope someone founds this one useful, see ya